# How to restrict access to .html pages using Spring Boot REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to restrict access to a page called `dashboard.html` to unauthenticated users. So far, I've had no success. Here's my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/",
                         "/login.html","/signup.html", "/videos/**",
                         "/login", "/logout", "/images/**", "/fonts/**",
                         "/css/**", "/js/**", "/pages/**", "/sass/**"
                         ).permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/dashboard/**", "/dashboard.html/**").authenticated()         
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter("/login", tokenAuthenticationService, userDetailsService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Whenever I have it set up this way, whenever I try to login, an infinite redirect loop is caused. The browser tries to navigate to `dashboard.html` but is restricted. This causes a redirect to the login page, which tries to redirect to the dashboard since there is a valid token.

If I have it set up like below, everyone can access `dashboard.html` and make calls to the `/dashboard` endpoint which is not desired:

```
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                     .antMatchers("/index.html", "/",
                             "/login.html","/signup.html", "/videos/**",
                             "/login", "/logout", "/images/**", "/fonts/**",
                             "/css/**", "/js/**", "/pages/**", "/sass/**",
                             "/dashboard/**", "/dashboard.html/**").permitAll()
                     .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                     .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

My login uses JWT tokens and uses the filter below to set the `SecurityContext` placeholder:

```
class StatelessLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    protected StatelessLoginFilter(String urlMapping, TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService,
            CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(urlMapping));
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        final BusinessUser user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), BusinessUser.class);
        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loginToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(loginToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final BusinessUser authenticatedUser = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
        final UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(authenticatedUser);

        tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, userAuthentication);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuthentication);
    }
```

I'm using the line `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuthentication);` to set the authentication. This works perfectly fine. If a user is found in the DB matching the credentials sent from the user, then the security context is usable to retrieve various data associated to the user.

**MY QUESTION:** How can I restrict the page `dashboard.html` and calls to the `/dashboard` endpoint to unauthenticated users (those without an authentication object inside the `SecurityContextHolder`)?

Comment: are you sure you want to give "/" in permit all, probably that causes it to allow all

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom `RequestMatcher` in combination with `denyAll`. First, your custom matcher:

```
public class PermittedPagesMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if (matchesToPaths(httpServletRequest,"/index.html", "/", "/login.html","/signup.html", "/videos/**", "/login", "/logout", "/images/**", "/fonts/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/pages/**", "/sass/**", "/dashboard/**", "/dashboard.html/**")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (matchesToPaths(httpServletRequest, "/dashboard/**", "/dashboard.html/**")) {
            return httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() == null;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean matchesToPaths(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, String... paths) {
        for (String p : paths) {
            if (new AntPathRequestMatcher(p).matches(httpServletRequest)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This custom `RequestMatcher` filters your request to permitted pages to all of your default pages and the dashboard is only available if the request is not authenticated.

Second, combine the matcher and `denyAll()`

```
 http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(new PermittedPagesMatcher())
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .antMatchers("/dashboard/**", "/dashboard.html/**")
            .denyAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
```

`denyAll()` ensures, that by default no one is allowed to access this page.

**Attention**: The order of permit and deny is important!

Comment: I want to NOT be able to access it while unauthenticated. With this set up, I'm still able to access it even if I do not have an authentication token. I modified the return statement to: `return httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() != null;` as it should return true only if there's an authenticated user. Now I'm running into the same issue. Nobody is allowed to access `dashboard.html` now. Even if they're authenticated. I want only authenticated / logged in users to be able to access dashboard.html. I can only get everyone to access it or nobody to access it right now.

Comment: I'm confused... Quote: _How can I restrict [...] calls to [...] to unauthenticated users._  If you want to permit authenticated users only, remove `"/dashboard/**"` and `"/dashboard.html/**"` from `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(....)` of your original code and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm having a problem with my original setup though. For some reason, I'm unable to access `/dashboard.html` with that setup whether I'm authenticated or not. I even printed out the value of `httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() != null;` and it returns true. So that means there's an authenticated user but for some reason I cannot access `/dashboard.html`.

Comment: Is it the order of my filters? A user is being put into the Principal object so the custom RequestMatcher should work but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have custom filters?

Comment: Should I not? Using a custom JWT filter implementation is the only way I could get authentication to work. Are there any security/authentication guides you can refer me to to possibly overhaul my current site authentication?

Comment: Did you have a look [here](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/)?